# mongodb datetime query for startdate and enddate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

its my mongodb table structure .

```
User = [
  {
    "name": "sumon",
    "Order" :[
      {
        "start_date":2019-04-22 23:08:39.927
        "end_date":2019-04-23 02:08:39.927
      },
      {
        "start_date":2019-04-22 23:08:39.927
        "end_date":2019-04-23 02:08:39.927
      },
      {
        "start_date":2019-04-22 23:08:39.927
        "end_date":2019-04-23 02:08:39.927
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "karim",
    "Order" :[
      {
        "start_date":2019-04-22 23:08:39.927
        "end_date":2019-04-23 02:08:39.927
      },
      {
        "start_date":2019-04-22 23:08:39.927
        "end_date":2019-04-23 02:08:39.927
      },
      {
        "start_date":2019-04-22 23:08:39.927
        "end_date":2019-04-23 02:08:39.927
      }
    ]
  }

]
```

Its my user table in mongodb . I need to find those user who has no order between
'2018-04-22 23:14:00' to '2018-04-22 23:50:00'

Comment: is your `start_date` and `end_date` not `ISODate` ? e.g: `"start_date" : ISODate("2019-04-22T23:08:39.927Z")`

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement you might need `elemMatch` operator, for details have a look at [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#elemmatch-query)

Using this you can perform be below query for your collection as:

```
 db.collcationName.find(
    {"Order" : 
        {$elemMatch: 
            {"start_date": {$not: { $gte: new ISODate('2018-04-22 23:14:00')} }, 
             "end_date": {$not: {$lt: new ISODate('2018-04-22 23:50:00')} } 
            } 
        } 
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need filter and count "useless" orders (order between '2018-04-22 23:14:00' to '2018-04-22 23:50:00') and than filter users who has no "useless" orders.

You can use aggregate like that

```
db.User.aggregate(
{
    $project: {
        'name': 1,
        Orders: {
            $filter: {
                input: '$Orders',
                as: 'order',
                cond: {
                    $or: [{
                            $and: [{
                                    $gte: ['$$order.end_date', ISODate('2019-04-22 23:14:00')]
                                },
                                {
                                    $lt: ['$$order.start_date', ISODate('2019-04-22 23:14:00')]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            $and: [{
                                    $gte: ['$$order.end_date', ISODate('2019-04-22 23:50:00')]
                                },
                                {
                                    $lt: ['$$order.start_date', ISODate('2019-04-22 23:50:00')]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            $and: [{
                                    $gte: ['$$order.start_date', ISODate('2019-04-22 23:14:00')]
                                },
                                {
                                    $lt: ['$$order.start_date', ISODate('2019-04-22 23:50:00')]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        'name': 1,
        'useless_orders': {
            $size: '$Orders'
        }
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        'useless_orders': 0
    }
}
)
```

This is guaranteed to works for the dataset:

```
> db.Users.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cbeb3ee382b79e4100195a6"),
    "name" : "kate",
    "Orders" : [
        {
            "start_date" : ISODate("2019-04-22T20:08:39.927Z"),
            "end_date" : ISODate("2019-04-22T23:08:39.927Z")
        },
        {
            "start_date" : ISODate("2019-04-22T20:08:39.927Z"),
            "end_date" : ISODate("2019-04-22T23:08:39.927Z")
        },
        {
            "start_date" : ISODate("2019-04-22T20:08:39.927Z"),
            "end_date" : ISODate("2019-04-22T23:08:39.927Z")
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cbeb597cf56f3e410320a96"),
    "name" : "karim",
    "Orders" : [
        {
            "start_date" : ISODate("2019-04-22T20:08:39.927Z"),
            "end_date" : ISODate("2019-04-22T23:08:39.927Z")
        },
        {
            "start_date" : ISODate("2019-04-22T09:00:00Z"),
            "end_date" : ISODate("2019-04-22T19:12:00Z")
        },
        {
            "start_date" : ISODate("2019-04-23T19:00:00Z"),
            "end_date" : ISODate("2019-04-23T20:59:00Z")
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cbeb5e7cf56f3e410320a97"),
    "name" : "sumon",
    "Orders" : [
        {
            "start_date" : ISODate("2019-04-22T13:30:00Z"),
            "end_date" : ISODate("2019-04-22T16:40:00Z")
        },
        {
            "start_date" : ISODate("2019-04-22T15:00:00Z"),
            "end_date" : ISODate("2019-04-22T19:12:00Z")
        },
        {
            "start_date" : ISODate("2019-04-23T19:00:00Z"),
            "end_date" : ISODate("2019-04-23T20:12:00Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @tapos-ghosh, may be you have to change date-format. I tested this request into mongodb compass.